# ASP.NET MVC и статические переменные

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Можно ли кэшировать данные в статических переменных? Что с ними происходит при перезапуске приложения? Речь только об MVC.

Comment: _Что с ними происходит при перезапуске приложения_ - очевидно они уничтожаются и создаются заново

Comment: Так происходит при iis recycle?

Comment: Какие события в Global.asax срабатывают, когда они уничтожаются и создаются заново - какие есть варианты?

Comment: нет никаких событий отслеживающих состояние статических переменных

Comment: Очевидно, что-то происходит до того, как они уничтожаются. Что же это может быть?

Comment: Откуда предположение, что что-то происходит? :-)